# Cannot iterate through List<someclass> in view of an mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model

The model to my view is list of a class. I tried to iterate through the list to bind the data to html.hiddenfor. But the data isn't rendered as expected.

```
@model List<MyApp.Tag.Sample_Tag>
<div class="form-group">
  @if (Model.Count > 0)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
      {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].is_selected, new {@id="hdnClientRoleChk-"+@Model[i].tag_id})
      }  
  }
</div>
```

When I inspect the page, I see some thing like this

```
<input id="hdnClientRoleChk-4" name="[4].is_selected" type="hidden" value="False">
```

Why is the name attribute deformed after render?

Comment: How did you expect it to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.Net razor view doesn't allow the user to use the expression in Helper tags.
There is no need to write extra code. You can use simple `foreach` to get the same result.

```
@model List<MyApp.Tag.Sample_Tag>
<div class="form-group">
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
     @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem=>item.is_selected, new {@id="hdnClientRoleChk-"+item.tag_id})
}
</div>
```

If you really need to use `for` loop you can use this code.

```
@model List<MyApp.Tag.Sample_Tag>
<div class="form-group">
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   {
       var is_selected = Model[i].is_selected;
       var tag_id = Model[i].tag_id;
       @Html.Hidden("is_selected", is_selected, new { @id="hdnClientRoleChk-"+tag_id})
   }  
}
</div>
```

Hopefully, this will solve your problem.